# shortcut to dial a two number phone number on Android

Tags: android, android-widget, telephony

I am developing an app for Android after doing the same on iOS. One of the features is to enable users to dial two numbers one after the other with one click of a button.

For example, say you want to dial 1-800-111-1111 and then an extension 123456. On iOS you can do: tel://18001111111p123456.

I did some digging around and could not find anything for Android. Can anyone suggest anything?

bunch of thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use commas instead of `p`. Each comma tells Android to wait for 2 seconds (or something like that) before dialing in the next set of numbers.

Edit:

Note that some users have reported that commas add less delay on some devices. By using multiple commas, you can increase the delay.

Comment: do you still need the tel://?

Comment: You dial it like any other number.

Comment: it opens the browser if i click on it from an email...thats what i am trying to accomplish: send someone a link (say, tel://12345,12233 like you suggested with the comma), that can be clickable and invoke the phone app.

Comment: That varies from Device to device. Some of them have any links set to open in a browser. Other filter the app based on the type of link.

Comment: would you recommend keeping the tel:// for those devices where it works?

Comment: As I don't have a complete list of those devices on which it works and doesn't work, I can't say. However, you have nothing to lose by leaving it in. Removing it completely will stop it from working on even the devices on which tell:// works. For the record, I can't get any format of tel:// to even become a link on my stock Galaxy Nexus, in the Gmail app.